# Print chart error: "User memory limit exceed"

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, array, regression

I tried to plot the SAR backscattering vs the Crop Water Stress Index using the following code:

```
var CWSI= ndvi.add(ndwi).rename('CWSI')
print('CWSI',CWSI)
Map.addLayer(CWSI.clip(Hoshiarpur),{},"CWSI",false)

    var sen_reduce = s1_preprocces_view.reduce({
                        reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
                       });
    
    Map.centerObject(parameter.GEOMETRY, 12);
    
    Map.addLayer(s1_view.first(), visparam, 'First image in the input S1 collection', false);
    Map.addLayer(s1_preprocces_view.first(), visparam, 'First image in the processed S1 collection', false);
    
    
     var visparam_mean = {bands:['VV_mean','VH_mean','VVVH_ratio_mean'], min: [0.01, 0.0032, 1.25],max: [1, 0.31, 31.62]}
    Map.addLayer(sen_reduce.clip(Hoshiarpur), visparam_mean, 'sen_reduce', true);
    
    /*--------------------------------------------Graph Generation---------------------------------------*/
    
    var array = sen_reduce.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: Hoshiarpur, scale: 1000});
                     //.toArray(merge.bandNames());
                     
    var array_1 = CWSI.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: Hoshiarpur, scale: 1000});
                     //.toArray(merge.bandNames());
                     
    var x = ee.List(array.get('VV_median')).slice(0,3959); //to make list of size equal to y we sliced elements of x
    var y = ee.List(array_1)//.slice();        
    
    print('x',x);
    print('y',y);
    
    // Define the chart and print it to the console.
    var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({array: y, axis: 0, xLabels: x}).setOptions({
      title: 'dB vs CWSI',
      colors: ['cf513e'],
      hAxis: {
        title: 'CWSI',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'db',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      dataOpacity: 0.5,
      legend: {position: 'bottom-right'},
    });
    
    print(chart);
```

But I got this error: "User memory limit exceeded" while printing the values of x and chart

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/01ca2af72a02d6f2537ac00a6ed083e6

Comment: can you share your asset 'users/omkarjadhav296/hoss'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your study area asset, like @OscarBau pointed out. The amount of memory used is very much dependent on the size of it.

Since you're requiring external libraries, this is a bit of a black box. But, the terrain flattening seems to be too expensive for you to add your analysis on top of it.

Just looking at your script, you can increase the `tileScale` of `reduceRegion()`. You could also consider using `bestEffort` together with `maxPixels`, to get better control how many pixels you collect into your arrays.

With this, your script runs for some areas at least:

```
var parameter = { //1. Data Selection
  START_DATE: "2018-05-01",
  STOP_DATE: "2018-06-30",
  POLARIZATION: 'VVVH',
  ORBIT: 'BOTH',
  GEOMETRY: Hoshiarpur, //uncomment if interactively selecting a region of interest
  //GEOMETRY: ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[104.80, 11.61],[104.80, 11.36],[105.16, 11.36],[105.16, 11.61]]], null, false), //Uncomment if providing coordinates
  //GEOMETRY: ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[112.05, -0.25],[112.05, -0.45],[112.25, -0.45],[112.25, -0.25]]], null, false),
  //2. Additional Border noise correction
  APPLY_ADDITIONAL_BORDER_NOISE_CORRECTION: true,
  //3.Speckle filter
  APPLY_SPECKLE_FILTERING: true,
  SPECKLE_FILTER_FRAMEWORK: 'MULTI',
  SPECKLE_FILTER: 'BOXCAR',
  SPECKLE_FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE: 15,
  SPECKLE_FILTER_NR_OF_IMAGES: 10,
  //4. Radiometric terrain normalization
  APPLY_TERRAIN_FLATTENING: false,
  DEM: ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003'),
  TERRAIN_FLATTENING_MODEL: 'VOLUME',
  TERRAIN_FLATTENING_ADDITIONAL_LAYOVER_SHADOW_BUFFER: 0,
  //5. Output
  FORMAT: 'DB',
  CLIP_TO_ROI: false,
  SAVE_ASSETS: false
}

...

var dBArray = ee.Array(ee.List(
  sen_reduce
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
      geometry: Hoshiarpur,
      scale: 2000,
      tileScale: 16
    })
    .get('VV_median')
))


var cwsiArray = ee.Array(ee.List(
  CWSI
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
      geometry: Hoshiarpur,
      scale: 2000,
      tileScale: 16
    })
    .get('CWSI')
))

var x = dBArray
var y = cwsiArray
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/442bc84616cd3c8efe1f0bccdea21bb7